# How to play akamai secure HD stream URL in JWPlayer

Tags: jwplayer, live-streaming, akamai

I am having JWPlayer ads version to play my on demand video and live stream. Recently i chose to move for secure HD stream url. I used akamai api to generate token and appended it to the stream url as suggested by akamai in their api.

But when i use this url in JW Player source, it gives error like "No playable sources found"

I got the url verified through akamai and they said that url is correct. Also this url is plying stream in VLC and quicktime player.

I tried the same url with newer version of JW Player but still got the same error.

How can i play this secure url in JW palyer. Please help.

My secure URL is like

http://XXXXXXXX.akamaihd-XXXXX.net/i/XXXXXXX_1@7821/master.m3u8?hdnts=st=1460021394~exp=1460027394~acl=/*~hmac=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder if JW Player is doing something hacky like looking at the file name extension rather than content type, and then parsing the URL incorrectly to get that extension.  Firstly, what do you see in your network tab?  Is the M3U8 downloaded at all?  Can you provide a signed URL for us to test with?

Comment: post your jwplayer embedded code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have fixed the problem. Actually i missed a setup attribute type:"hls" in my configuration, thats why jwplayer is not capturing the hls url.

Comment: @nikhilkhare could you share your JW Player setup? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @cito here is my test setup http://cdn.abplive.in/vodnew/vod-hindi-tokenized.html